# Is there any Vedantic teacher or organisation who uses pure reasoning to explain Vedanta?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

I fully believe in the Upanishads. But, is there any teacher who teaches Vedanta, using pure reasoning? I am interested to learn. Thanks.

Comment: Vedanta Paribhasha , a prakarana grantha (introductory treatise) by Shri Dharmaraja Adhvarindra.  uses reasoning to teach vedanta

Comment: See Gaudapada's Karika (Commentary) on the Mandukya Upanishad here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mandukya-upanishad-karika-bhashya